# Close a WPF window separately

Tags: c#, wpf

Goal:
Enable closing of the application's window(s) independently without affecting others. The application is created in WPF.

Problem:

> Can't close the window(s)

In winform, it is enough to have the code `winform.close()` to close down the window but it doesn't work in WPF.

You can have this code to close a specfic window:

```
Application.Current.Windows[0].Close();
```

but how would it work if you have many windows and you want to close a specific window without affecting the others?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588798.aspx) class to get the windows through [Application.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx)-property exactly as you described. If you are in the code-behind of the window, call `this.Close();`

**Configuration for multiple Windows**
Set the main window to the [Application.MainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx) property and set the [Application.ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) to a appropriate value if you also want to hold the app open, if the main window is closed (e.g `App.Current.ShutdownMode=ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;` ).

I have already observed, that some people have had problems with the ShutdownMode. A workaround for this is to open the first window invisible and from this window, you open the visible application windows. This prevents the application from closing if the first created window will be closed. However you should be able to resolve this problem also over the ShutdownMode-property.
In scenarios with multiple windows, you can use [Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx) to close the app without closing every window.

I hope this answer is what your question is about. Make a comment if not.

Comment: "I have already observed, that some people have had problems with the ShutdownMode. A workaround for this is to open the first window invisible and from this window, you open the visible application windows. "

Is it property "visibility" that you are focusing?

Comment: @FullmetalBoy: Yes, you can let the application open the first window, create some new Window-instances and set the Visibility of the first window to hidden. But as I wrote, this should not be necessary if you set the ShutdownMode accordingly (as far as I remember, you have to do it OnStartup before any other action took place). The following post explains some things about the WPF-application start. It may be interesting for you: http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-wpf-application-class-overview-and-gotcha/

Answer (score 10):

I am agree with HCL. You can use `this.Close();` from code-behind of the window, this will close WPF window as like `winform.close();`.

Or you can use following code for get the specific window for close

```
Window win = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.Name == "Window Name");
win.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this code to close the most recent window

```
Application.Current.Windows[Application.Current.Windows.Count - 1].Close();
```